# Generating Images really fast

Tags: php, javascript, html, canvas

I am creating an app that lets you preview fonts on the web, in the same way [myfonts](http://www.myfonts.com/search/tag%3asansserif/fonts/) does it. Anyone know how they do it so fast?

My method  is to generate font previews usign HTML5 Canvas and some Javascript. This is an alternative to doing it server side and generating images using PHP GD library or Imageick.

However, although using HTML5 canvas makes things lightining fast and all the processing is on the client side. I am having trouble hiding the fonts that I load because I have to use font-face to load the fonts:

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Press Start 2P';
        src: url('fonts/PressStart2P.ttf');
    }
```

And use JS to render to the canvas:

```
        $('#draw').click(function () {
            var canvas = $('canvas')[0],
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.font = '12px "Press Start 2P"';
            ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
            ctx.fillText('Hello, world!', x, y += 20);
            ctx.fillRect(x - 20, y - 10, 10, 10);
        });
```

Any ideas on how I can keep the font paths secret or any other alternative methods to generating images really quickly. I need to generate about 40+ images on each page very frequently.

Comment: I'd imagine they probably cache the rendered fonts server side, so they don't have to be generated on every view. As for keeping stuff secret on the web, you can't.  HTML and HTTP were built to be open standards.  If you can access a resource to view it, you can get details on where that resource is stored.

Comment: You're right, I thought I could load up the fonts using AJAX but that can easily be sniffed out.

Comment: myfons does the rendering on the server side. They send an ajax call with the text and font information from the page  and get back a json object with the images to show.

Comment: @Abs what technology did you eventually choose for fast image generation on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think they generate them really fast at all. The text is static, and cannot be changed by the user, so they can just pregenerate all images.

If you need your text to be dynamic, indeed you have the option of rendering on the client side or on the server side.

If you want to "hide" the font from the user, the only way is server-side rendering. There really is no way to allow the browser to use the font, but not allow the user to save it to wherever they like. They can just use the Chrome Inspector or Firebug to access any resource downloaded by your web page, no matter how well you obfuscate the URL.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Client side rendering has so many benefits but I don't want everyone to have access to the fonts. Btw, myfonts does allow you change the text, color and background/foreground and size. Not a great interface but it works!

Comment: Well, if you want to jump through many hoops, you *could* prerender every glyph to a separate image and combine them on the client side. But I doubt it'll be faster than server-side rendering, and it will be really hard to get the kerning right.

Comment: Yeah, I think I should stick to generating on the server side and try to come up with any optimization that can improve speed.